# How to push some values inside string like array in jQuery/Angular 7

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I have some checkboxes whose values coming from loop, I am pushing those values into array, but here my requirement is that instead of pushing into array I need to just join those values like "parent1", "parent2", "parent3" and console it. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let child of nestedjson; let i = index"><input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="{{child.name}}" checked>{{child.name}}</li>
<div><button (click)="clear()" type="submit">clear</button></div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';
import Speech from 'speak-tts';
import {
  RxSpeechRecognitionService,
  resultList,
} from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

  providers: [RxSpeechRecognitionService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  showit: any;
  nestedjson: any;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nestedjson = [{
        name: "parent1",
        value: ["child11", "child12"]
      },
      {
        name: "parent2",
        value: ["child2"]
      },
      {
        name: "parent3",
        value: ["child3"]
      }
    ];
    this.showit = true;

  }

  clear() {
    var x = [];
    $(".myCheckbox:checked").each(function() {
      x.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(x);
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the question here? If you need to join them, you can use `join()`, but using `console.log()` will do basically the same...

Comment: I tried but its not working clear(){
var x = $(".myCheckbox:checked").each(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join();
console.log(x);
}

Comment: You changed your code... If you keep your code as is and just do `console.log(x.join())`, what happens?

Comment: As of my older code my output will come like  ["parent1", "parent2", "parent3"] but I don't want array I just need  "parent1", "parent2", "parent3"

Comment: `console.log(x.join())` would not print the brackets...

Comment: yes you are correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use jQuery with Angular if at all possible. You'll mess up how Angular's change detection works.

Second, or maybe more of a corollary to the first, if you want to retrieve UI state in your components, you model it in. You have a list of strings and you want to make them checkboxes. Instead, model them as something like:

```
class StringOption {
  public Text: string;
  public Value: string;
  public Checked: bool;
}
```

Let the model decide if the checkbox is checked and that way you don't have to query the DOM to get the state. Then building a string of the text or values of all checked options can be done like so:

```
let selected = options.filter(opt => opt.Checked).map(opt => opt.Text).join(', ');
```

Comment: what is options here? I am getting blank output

Comment: The `StringOption[]` you bound to the UI. It's the alternative to using your nestedJson. Really all you'd have to do is add `Checked` to each entry in your nestedJson and bind that field to the checkbox and you can ditch jQuery.